# Detecting Which Page is Referencing a PHP Generated JavaScript file

Tags: php, javascript

I am generating a JS navigation using PHP.  Script is included like so

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/topNav.js.php'></script>
```

I would like to use PHP rather than JavaScript to assign the class for the current page's link but all of the $_SERVER vars see the topNav.js.php location.

I know I could use JS something  like

```
if(window.location.href == 'myurl') {
    document.getElementById('itemx').className += 'active';
}
```

but I wanted to know if there was a good way to do this via PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a PHP footer include I had not considered.  Just added

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <? $pg = preg_replace('/\//', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
    document.getElementById('nav_<?=$pg?>').className += ' qmactive ';
  </script>
```

Lazy and functional.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the current page into Javascript with PHP before calling your "external" script file.

Something like...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    echo "var CurrentPage = '" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "';";
?>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/topNav.js.php'></script>
```

This variable will be usable in your external script. You can set something in your external script to make sure it has a value if you do not manually set it outside. That would be a good practice for error handling.